# How to utilize hardware decode for audio?

Tags: ios, ffmpeg, core-audio, audioqueue

I have a buffer that contain packets read by ffmpeg from a video file encoded using H264/AAC
According to Apple document, audio stream encoded in AAC can be decode with hardware support,

how to decode the audio stream with hardware support ?

UPDATE: I use Audio Queue Service to output the audio. Right now i decode AAC packet using ffmpeg and send LPCM audio to AQS. According to the Apple document, I can send directly AAC audio to AQ and it will take care of decoding task. Does it decode with hardware? Do i need, and how to set Audio Queue's parameter to enable audio hardware decoding?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can tell the system to not use hardware decoding but probably not the other way around.

constant to determine which hardware codecs can be used.

```
enum {
    kAudioFormatProperty_HardwareCodecCapabilities = 'hwcc',
};
```

Constants
`kAudioFormatProperty_HardwareCodecCapabilities`
A UInt32 value indicating the number of codecs from the specified list that can be used, if the application were to begin using them in the specified order. Set the `inSpecifier` parameter to an array of `AudioClassDescription` structures that describes a set of one or more audio codecs. If the property value is the same as the size of the array in the `inSpecifier` parameter, all of the specified codecs can be used.
Available in iOS 3.0 and later.
Declared in AudioFormat.h.
Discussion
Use this property to determine whether a desired set of codecs can be simultaneously instantiated.

Hardware-based codecs can be used only when playing or recording using Audio Queue Services or using interfaces, such as AV Foundation, which use Audio Queue Services. In particular, you cannot use hardware-based audio codecs with OpenAL or when using the I/O audio unit.

When describing the presence of a hardware codec, the system does not consider the current audio session category. Some categories disallow the use of hardware codecs. A set of hardware codecs is considered available, by this constant, based only on whether the hardware supports the specified combination of codecs.

Some codecs may be available in both hardware and software implementations. Use the `kAudioFormatProperty_Encoders` and `kAudioFormatProperty_Decoders` constants to determine whether a given codec is present, and whether it is hardware or software-based.

Software-based codecs can always be instantiated, so there is no need to use this constant when using software encoding or decoding.

The following code example illustrates how to check whether or not a hardware AAC encoder and a hardware AAC decoder are available, in that order of priority:

```
AudioClassDescription requestedCodecs[2] = {
    {
        kAudioEncoderComponentType,
        kAudioFormatAAC,
        kAppleHardwareAudioCodecManufacturer
    },
    {
        kAudioDecoderComponentType,
        kAudioFormatAAC,
        kAppleHardwareAudioCodecManufacturer
    }
};

UInt32 successfulCodecs = 0;
size = sizeof (successfulCodecs);
OSStatus result =   AudioFormatGetProperty (
                        kAudioFormatProperty_HardwareCodecCapabilities,
                        requestedCodecs,
                        sizeof (requestedCodecs),
                        &size,
                        &successfulCodecs
                    );
switch (successfulCodecs) {
    case 0:
        // aac hardware encoder is unavailable. aac hardware decoder availability
        // is unknown; could ask again for only aac hardware decoding
    case 1:
        // aac hardware encoder is available but, while using it, no hardware
        // decoder is available.
    case 2:
        // hardware encoder and decoder are available simultaneously
}
```

https://github.com/mooncatventures-group/sampleDecoder

You probably better off using audioUnits however rather than audio queue

Comment: Thanks for the answer, in the code from the provided links is really helpful. In the code, AQ's buffers are filled with LPCM data, it means the audio samples must be decoded before sending to AQS. But I want to send AAC audio packet directly to the AQS.

Comment: ok, if you have aac source you are correct you can decode the compressed source using aq https://github.com/mooncatventures-group/iFrameExtractor/tree/master/Classes

Comment: I tested on ip4/ios6, there is no sound. The video encoded as H264 BaselineL1.3 / AAC LC. There maybe something wrong in audio stream description.

Comment: its set up for aac with 1 channel so you may have to tweak the description somewhat but its definitely is the code you need. We've tested with audio from ip cams and it works great. If you need help you could consider contracting with us. you might try forcing an arbitrarlly large pre-buffer and see if that helps.Usually no sound issues are caused by insufficient buffer allocation, see code example below

Comment: Has anyone actually gotten the above code snippet for testing kAudioFormatProperty_HardwareCodecCapabilities to work? (You need to swap the 2nd and 3rd parameters, which are in the wrong order.)  I always get kAudioFormatUnsupportedPropertyError.

Answer (score 1):

You can, though as usual with Core Audio there are various caveats and edge cases to watch for.

Set the property `kExtAudioFileProperty_CodecManufacturer` to `kAppleHardwareAudioCodecManufacturer`. Do this before you set the client data format.

Some docs in `ExtendedAudioFile.h`

Comment: thanks, but can you please more specific about how to do it? I have a queue of ffmpeg audio packet (encoded in AAC). Right now i use ffmpeg to decode audio stream and feed the decode audio (LPCM) to Audio Queue  Service. Is there anyway to tell Audio Queue Service to use hardware to decode AAC stream?

Comment: The short answer is that the system will decode with the hardware decoder whenever it can—i.e., if you're only decoding one stereo AAC stream at a time. If the system doesn't use the hardware decoder because it's otherwise occupied, there's no way to force it.

Answer (score 0):

rather than doing this calculation just force a very large buffer size here.

status = AudioQueueAllocateBufferWithPacketDescriptions(audioQueue_, 
        _audioCodecContext->bit_rate * kAudioBufferSeconds / 8, 
        _audioCodecContext->sample_rate * kAudioBufferSeconds / 
          _audioCodecContext->frame_size + 1, 
        &audioQueueBuffer_[i]);

Answer (score 0):

Found this:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1663/_index.html

Since the AudioFormatGetProperty doesn't work too often.  The above describes how to use AudioFormatGetPropetyInfo for the Encoder or decoder and detect which is present in HW or SW.